# for React-bootstrap grid, how do you use bsPrefix in a Col?

Tags: react-bootstrap

Running into a gap in documentation...
I need to vertical align content in one column of a grid fluid column to the bottom.

The documentation suggests I can inject css into `<Col xs={2}>` by using bsPrefix, but doesn't give any examples of syntax..

Using `<Col bsPrefix={'col-cs-2 vbottom'}>` actually strips off the css..

Does anyone know how to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok doco was misleading and incomplete.. surprise :)

bsPrefix needs to be paired with xs={2} and would re-write the 'col' potion

What I needed was the undocumented className

eg somewhat yuck solution to bottom align object to column was:-

add

```
.vbottom {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-top: 320px;
  }
```

to global styles
and use

```
<Col xs={2} className='vbottom'>
```

which renders to `<div class="vbottom col-xs-2">`

Answer (score 1):

The bsPrefix is used to modify the prefix that is being used in the generated css class names.

`<Col bsPrefix="my-col" md=4>` would end up with class names like `my-col my-col-md-4`.

I'm thinking you should just be able to give the content of your Col an `align-self: flex-end` since the whole thing is based on flexbox.

Comment: so add a class "align-self: flex-end" to the Col?

Comment: The child of the Col would have a class that applies that style

Comment: <Col><div className="myChild">test</div></Col>

Comment: I've got it working at the moment with the vbottom style having a margin-top.. but I don't like it since it feel fragile..

Comment: .myChild { align-self: flex-end }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188379/discussion-between-baradhili-and-gregory-friedman).